# Paint over multiple UVmaps?

Tags: texture-painting

Would it be possible to paint over an object with multiple UVmaps, as for example the result of ctrl+J'ing several independently UVmapped objects?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44419/uv-mapping-lost-when-joining-mesh

Comment: interesting. i'm changinig me some uvmap names then, and see how it goes. cheers!